# $expand on Lookup field without referential integrity

Tags: odata

I have a query using the listservice where I'm trying to resolve a Lookup field - however not every row in the parent list has a row in the child list.

If I run my query as below I just get a 'An error occurred while processing this request.' response.

```
https://mysite/subsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList?$select=Identifier,ListRef/Status&$expand=ListRef
```

but If I include a filter to only read entries  I know have a match (like below) it works fine

```
https://mysite/subsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList?$select=Identifier,ListRef/Status&$filter=isLookupRow eq 'Y'&$expand=ListRef
```

based on that I'm assuming the error is due to trying to expand a row without a match, is there a mechanism for expand to return the list but 'ignore' (provide and empty value) for those cases where there's no corresponding lookup match.

further validation that it's related to the lookup reference.

**EDIT**
If I run the same query filtered for a single item that does NOT have a reference in the lookup field it still fails with the same error.

However, if I then edit that list item and change the lookup field value from 'None' to a value that exists in my second list it does return sucessfully.

Comment: `$expand` does not have any dependence with `$filter`. It seems error is occurring from a different source

Comment: Are you saying $expand will attempt to lookup for all rows in my list  regardless of the filter (even in the case where the filter would return a single row) ? That seems like an odd architectural decision from a performance point of view  - reference?